# Magento2 which css to modify for navigation menu

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Hi I'm trying modify the top navigation in the frontpage. 
Closer inspection shows that it belongs to this class,

```
.rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav 
li.rd-navbar--has-dropdown:before, .rd-navbar-static .rd-navbar-nav li.rd-navbar--has-megamenu>a:before {content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Material Icons";
  font-weight: 400;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  transform: translate(0, 0); }
```

however after grepping my system I find a list of files that contains the keyword I need.

```
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/fonts/material-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/source/_variables.scss
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/source/.sass-cache/36ebafa5c6a78e91d6c5a10f3c7799a46af04876/_variables.scssc
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/style.css
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/modules.css
/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/material-icons.css
/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/fonts/material-icons/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot
/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/source/_variables.scss
/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/modules.min.css
/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/style.min.css
/var/www/html/pub/static/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/material-icons.min.css
/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/source/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/modules.min.css
/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/source/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/style.min.css
/var/www/html/var/view_preprocessed/source/frontend/TM/Spice/en_US/css/material-icons.min.css
```

the questions is which of these files is the one I need to modify? For example say I want to change the font to Arial.  thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the CSS files located under your custom theme

`/var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/`

Or add a new CSS file in that location with your changes and link it in the appropriate  xml layout file

DO NOT edit anything in other locations since those files get updated or deleted by Magento and all your changes will get lost.

Comment: thanks, however I'm a bit confused since I'm trying to modify an exisiting template, Spice?  How do would I modify this? thanks.

Comment: Try adding your changes to the end of this file

Comment: /var/www/html/app/design/frontend/TM/Spice/web/css/style.css

Comment: thanks that is what I thought originally as well;  do you know if I have to redeploy static?  For example, does style.css generate the style.min.css which then generate the cache version? What creates this, the static deployment or the cache flush?

Comment: Just flush the cache and if your in development mode you shouldn't worry about static deployment.

Comment: thanks, finally got it to work by flushing the javascript/css in addition to the normal flush; moreover in google chrome I had to disable cache in devtool;

Comment: I usually just ssh to there and and run `php bin/magento cache:clean` and `php bin/magento cache:flush` sometimes I just disable cache with `php bin/magento cache: disable` but this slows the page load